# Custom ListView with CheckBox

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-cursor

I know there are lots of questions related to Custom ListView with CheckBox but still i am getting some problem in retrieving all checked items.

What i am doing is :

Displaying Custom ListView from Database (List of All Sent SMSs).

Allow user to check various list items.

When user presses the Delete Button i want to delete all the checked items (From the database as well as the view portion)

**Problem :**
When i go to my Activity for the first time and check some items, and delete it, it works fine.

But when i again check some items just after pressing delete button, some items gets checked and some gets unchecked and again some other items are deleted..

I think i am not able to bind id and list item perfectly..

**Coding done so far**:

row.xml contains

```
ImageView
TextView
TextView
TextView
CheckBox
```

In my Activity Class :

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null);
String[] from={"address","body"};
int[] to={R.id.contactName,R.id.msgLine};
ssa=new SentSmsAdapter(context,R.layout.inbox_list_item,cursor,from,to,2);   
smsList.setAdapter(ssa);

deleteSms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ArrayList<Boolean> list=SentSmsAdapter.itemChecked;

                Uri path=Uri.parse("content://sms/");
                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                {
                    if(list.get(i))
                        getContentResolver().delete(path,"_id="+ssa.getItemId(i),null);
                }

                ssa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have custom SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
 public class SentSmsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    Cursor dataCursor;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context context;
    int layoutType;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    public static HashMap<String,Long> myList=new HashMap<String,Long>();

    public static ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    public static ArrayList<Long> itemIds=new ArrayList<Long>();

    public SentSmsAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor, String[] from,
                    int[] to,int type) {
            super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);


            layoutType=type;
            this.context=context;
            this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        itemChecked.add(i, false);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_list_item, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();

             holder.checkBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkMsg);
             holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
             holder.cName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
             holder.icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgImage);
             holder.msg=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgLine);
             holder.time=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgTime);



             convertView.setTag(holder);
             holder.checkBox.setTag(itemChecked.get(position));
            }
            else
            {
                    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

              holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkMsg);
                                            int pos=Integer.parseInt(holder.checkBox.getTag());

                                     itemChecked.set(position, cb.isChecked());

                                            /*if (cb.isChecked()) {
                                    itemChecked.set(position, true);

                                    Log.i("WhenChecked",Boolean.toString(itemChecked.get(position)));
                                    // do some operations here
                                }
                                            else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                                    itemChecked.set(position, false);
                                    Log.i("WhenNotChecked",Boolean.toString(itemChecked.get(position)));
                                    // do some operations here
                                }
                                    */

                                    }
                            });

            dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

            String id=Integer.toString(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            itemIds.add(Long.parseLong(id));

            String msgText=dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            holder.msg.setText(msgText);

            Long time=dataCursor.getLong(dataCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
            holder.time.setText(Long.toString(time));

            String address=dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));

            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));           
            Cursor cs= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

            if(cs.getCount()>0)
                    address=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

            cs.close();
            holder.cName.setText(address);


            if(layoutType==1)holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
            {
                    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            arrayList.add(id+","+address+","+msgText+","+Long.toString(time));
            return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
            ImageView icon;
            CheckBox checkBox;
            TextView cName;
            TextView msg;
            TextView time;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemIds.get(position);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this.

add this code in getView()

```
holder.checkBox.seTag(position);
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(this);
```

implement this outside getView().

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view,boolean isChecked) {

  if(isChecked)
    {
      itemChecked.add(view.getTag());                          
    }
    else
    {
        if(itemChecked.cantains(view.getTag()))
          //remove from itemChecked.
    }
}
```

When deleting delete all the elements from the list whose index is available in itemChecked.

Comment: I have a class similar to that of Kartik, but I'm using an ArrayAdapter. When one of the checkBoxes is clicked, the onCheckChanged event is called for all of them. The fact that I use an ArrayAdapter should not change this right?

Comment: I used onClick instead of onCheckedChanged like I read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438375/custom-listview-with-checkbox-problem) and I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you use threads when checking, uncheking and deleting your items, they will work properly.