# ListView maintain state using Tag?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Apparently my thinking has some flaw as it's not working correctly. Basically, I'm trying to solve this problem: [listview with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438375/custom-listview-with-checkbox-problem)

In the answer, people suggested to create a global data structure to hold the state, which made sense. However, I thought if I'm using ViewHolder pattern, I could use the tag as the structure to store state information?

```
cbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        P tag = (P) ((View) v.getParent()).getTag();
        if(tag.cbox.isChecked())
            tag.cbox.setChecked(true);
        else
            tag.cbox.setChecked(false);
        //tag.cbox.toggle();
        Log.d("YoYo", Boolean.toString(tag.cbox.isChecked()));
    }
});
```

The code above did not toggle my checkbox in the rows. What did I do wrong?

**Update:** Rather then toggle, manual if statement seemed to work. Though, I'm running into another problem, where the checked state mess up after I scroll to different places. Why is that? If I set the checked state in the tag.cbox, isn't the check state unique to that object only?

---

**Update2: I follow other's suggestion and got a working version, but I'm still wondering why setTag/getTag not working?**

Working:

```
   public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Plurker tag = getItem(position);
        if (view == null)
            view = adapterLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, null);                
        tag.avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
        tag.cbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cBox);
        tag.cbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean isChecked)
            {
                int pos = position;
                Plurker p = getItem(pos);
                p.isChecked = isChecked;
                Log.d("PLURK", "Listener:" + p.toString());
            }
        });
        tag.update(getItem(position));
        Log.d("PLURK", tag.cbox.getText() + ":" + Integer.toString(position));

        return view;
    }
```

Not working:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    Plurker tag = getItem(position);
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = adapterLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, null);
        tag.avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
        tag.cbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cBox);    
        tag.cbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                int pos = position;
                Plurker p = getItem(pos);
                p.isChecked = !p.isChecked;
                Log.d("PLURK", "Listener:" + p.toString());
            }
        });
        view.setTag(tag);
    }
    else
        tag = (Plurker) view.getTag();

    tag.update(getItem(position));
    Log.d("PLURK", tag.cbox.getText() + ":" + Integer.toString(position));

    return view;
}
```

In the "not working" version, I need to use onClick instead of onCheckedChanged event, because when the view from hidden to reappear, it called the event listener, so it would falsely triggered.

Comment: Based on what the link is saying they want you to store the check status in a String array instead of tag. Try it and hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: @maebe Thanks! but I don't think that's the issue. In fact, I solved the first issue, but have another problem now :S

Comment: @Patrick What you are looking for ?

Comment: @Samir Hi, I'm looking why click on first row's checkbox, scroll down, the 9th and 18th checkbox also got selected.

Comment: @Patrick see my answer and its works definately for me And its have source below and its Multiple Item Selected listview......

Answer (score 1):

Are you inflating a new view each time or making use of the convertView that is passed in?

Normally the Adapter tries to recycle views, only creating enough to provide smooth scrolling. The existing recycled views are passed in as convertView. You can either inflate and return a new view every time (expensive) or just re-setup the convertView (if it exists) based on position. If recycling you need to re-set all the view attributes, as there is no guarantee that the recycled view you get is the same one used for this position in the past.

It sounds like your bug is that you are not correctly re-setting all the attributes of the recycled view (convertView) to match the data for the current position.

Comment: So if I reuse the view, do I need to set the listener again? (I will assume so, but just double check)